# For a normed space, is a vector subspace of it with the restriction norm also a normed space?

Tags: normed-spaces

**Question.** Let $X = (X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space and let $S \subset X$ be a subspace of $X$. Is $S$ a normed space (with the norm $\|\cdot\|$ of $X$) ?

**My intuition.** All we need to say for $S$ to be a normed space is that $S$ is a vector space and that $\|\cdot\|$ defines a norm on $S$. Since $S$ is a subspace of $X$, it also verifies the axioms to be a vector space and thus, $S$ is a vector space. On the other hand, if $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $X$ it will surely also be a norm on $S$. Thus, the answer is affirmative.

Is my thinking correct?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Your intuition is absolutely fine. Just write it down in a formal way, it will become the answer.

Comment: Why do you say stupid?

Comment: @Ajay I don't know, I feel like I shouldn't be confused over this.

Comment: I would suggest to improve the title to something like "is a normed subspace a normed space itself?"

Comment: @PeterFranek Done!

Comment: It is true in a metric space in general for any part ; but here we have to care about sum and external product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a real normed vector space and let $S\subset X$ a subspace of $X$.

1. $S$ is a vector space(in particular $0\in S)$;
2. Let $$\|.\|_S:S\to \Bbb R^+$$
   $$x\mapsto \|x\|$$

Then

a) $\forall \lambda \in \Bbb R,\forall x\in S ,\|\lambda x\|_S=\|\lambda x\|=|\lambda|\| x\|=|\lambda|\| x\|_S$;

b) $\| 0\|_S=\| 0\|=0;$

c) $\forall x\in S, $ if $\| x\|_S=0$, then $\| x\|=0$, then $x=0$;

d) $\forall x,y \in S, \| x+y\|_S=\| x+y\|$ and $\| x+y\|\leq\| x\|+\| y\|$, i.e. $\| x+y\|_S\leq\| x\|_S+\| y\|_S$

Thus, $(S,\|.\|_S)$ is a real normed vector space.

Answer (score -1):

If $X=B_1(0)$, the unit ball in $R^n$ under Euclidean norm, you can not take a linear subspace of it.

A topological subspace inherits the topology of the space.

Let $E\subset X$ be a subspace.

Then every open set $U\subset E$
is an intersection  $V\cap E$ where $V$ is an open subset of $X$.

Thus:
$(\forall x)(x\in U \implies x\in V\cap E\implies x\in V\implies (\exists B_r(x))(B_r(x)\subset V\cap E))$

Since $U=\cup_x{B_r(x)}$

$U$ is defined by the norm topology of $X$.

Comment: The question is about normed spaces, not normable topological vector spaces.

Comment: Not all normed spaces are linear spaces.

Comment: Assuming that by "linear space" you mean a vector space (in the algebraic sense; e.g. not [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_space_(geometry))), then the OP's usage of "normed space" (which is fairly common, but maybe not universal if you've seen otherwise -- perhaps [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/491197/13130) is an example) implies that all normed spaces are linear spaces: "*All we need to say for* $S$ *to be a normed space is that* $S$ *is a vector space and* $\ldots$"

Comment: seems unrelated